# Set of matrices invariant under multiplication by an external matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, cyclic-groups

I'm looking for the set of matrices (name and properties if possible) which is closed under multiplication by another matrix.

**Example:**

a set of matrices S=$\{\mathbf{A}_1,\mathbf{A}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{A}_n\}$ and an external matrix $\mathbf{B}$ such that $\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}_i=\mathbf{A}_j \quad\forall\, i,j \in \{1\ldots n\},~i \neq j$.

Comment: If the matrix $B$ is invertible, $S$  is the union of some of the orbits of the group $\langle B \rangle$ acting by left multiplication on the set of all matrices.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" set of matrices? There are many such sets.

Comment: You could also just say that the set is "left-invariant under multiplication by $B$".

Answer (score 0):

To amplify on Servaes's comment:

For any invertible matrix $B$, consider the following two sets:

$$
S_1 = \{0\}\\
S_2 = \{ \ldots, B^{-2}, B^{-1}, I, B, B^2, \ldots\}\\
$$

For each of these, we have $B\cdot S_i = S_i$. So the idea that there's such a thing as "**the** set" with this property is ill-founded.

For $B$ not invertible, $S_1$ is still a left-invariant set; there *may* be no others, however (as can be seen in the case where $B = 0$).